# Refresh search results

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook VBA macro that archives a mail item intelligently according to the archive folder of that account. However, sometimes when it archives an item, the item does not immediately disappear from the search results. It remains selected and the preview pane displays an error. I think I may be able to solve this by refreshing the search results. I am looking for either:

1. A `search.Refresh()` function/sub/thingy to refresh the search results.
2. Access to the current search text in order to refresh the results

like so:

```
'Get the current search text. Is this possible?
txtSearch = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.GetMeTheCurrentSearchTextScotty
'Search for nothing
myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search "", olSearchScopeAllFolders    
'Restore search
myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
```

Is it possible to refresh the search?

Comment: Other options - refresh the pane? refresh the mail item?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by saving the current search string to a global variable every time I do a search in my macros. Then I use that global variable later on to "refresh" the search. But this only works if my current search was set by a macro. If I manually search for something, this doesn't update the global variable and thus doesn't work properly.

This fits my usage 80% of the time, but it would be nice to have something better.

Comment: ,Maybe [How do i capture the text in the Instant Search box in Outlook 2010 in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850273/9439330)
 fits your needs or you have to create a form with a control that provides events.